# ssrs return max date from multiple lines with identical invoice numbers

Tags: t-sql, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, report-designer

ok, I'm pulling invoices with unique dates but identical invoice numbers. I want to pull only the lines with the largest date, ignoring the rest. I've tried grouping the DATE by max() but it still returns all dates for that invoice.
 is there an equivalent to lastdate() that I can use in ssrs? 
    select max(order.date) as maxDate

I've tried using max() in the report designer as well, but still returns all dates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do this in the report designer then you should set a row group of Invoice in your table / matrix and select `=Max(Fields!YourDateValue.Value)` in the cell where you wish to display.

Comment: I feel like I tried this, but my query might disallow this to work. I'll check it out on monday! :)

Answer (score 1):

So you want to select the max date, and only see one row for each invoice. Right?

I believe you want to group by invoice numbers, to squish those all down into one row for each.

```
SELECT MAX(myDateRow), Invoice, AnyOtherColumn
FROM myTable
GROUP BY Invoice, AnyOtherColumn
```

You may need to add WHERE MAX(myDateRow), but I don't think so.  Can we see your query so far?

Comment: I'll post something up when I have access to the server on monday

Comment: both of those were helpful, the problem is with my query - I've got too much info to pull and the group by's are corrupting the results :-/

Comment: Try cutting your query down into simple pieces. That will help determine which section is causing problems. I.E. drop as many columns and tables as you can while still producing the error. I slim down my queries all the time to track down finicky little issues. Odds are you'll see the issue when it's simpler. Then pull out any company identifying info and post the query.

Comment: the only way I was able to do with with the other information I was trying to extrapolate was to create a view with the maxdate being returned and filter my other query through that view. it worked, fortunately - though I was hoping there'd be a way to do it within the single query - too many variables